# pyjwt[crypto] 2.0.0 update incompatible with django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, pyjwt

I have a project that uses `django-allauth 0.44.0.` **Yesterday (12/22/20)** `pyjwt` update your version to `2.0.0.` When I try to install my dependencies running `pip`, return this error message, using `docker-compose`:

```
Collecting pyjwt[crypto]>=1.7
ERROR: In --require-hashes mode, all requirements must have their versions pinned with ==. These do not:
pyjwt[crypto]>=1.7 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/5f/5cff1c3696e0d574f5741396550c9a308dde40704d17e39e94b89c07d789/PyJWT-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=5c.... (from django-allauth==0.44.0->-r requirements-dev.txt (line 125))
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements-dev.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

In Poetry.lock:

```
[[package]]
name = "django-allauth"
version = "0.44.0"
description = "Integrated set of Django applications addressing authentication, registration, account management as well as 3rd party (social) account authentication."
category = "main"
optional = false
python-versions = "*"

[package.dependencies]
Django = ">=2.0"
pyjwt = {version = ">=1.7", extras = ["crypto"]}
python3-openid = ">=3.0.8"
requests = "*"
requests-oauthlib = ">=0.3.0"

[[package]]
name = "pyjwt"
version = "1.7.1"
description = "JSON Web Token implementation in Python"
category = "main"
optional = false
python-versions = "*"
```

Anybody do have the same issue? Thanks

Comment: If you update pyjwt 2.0.0 the error is solved, but it should not force update libraries dependencies too.

Answer (score 0):

i face same problem, just install little bit higher version of all-auth ( pip install django-allauth==0.31.0 ) and error go.